# Spring Integration - http outbound gateway custom headers

Tags: http, header, spring-integration, outbound

I have java object that I would like to pass as a custom header to my request on the http outbound gateway. Below is a snippet

```
<int:gateway id="service" service-interface="MyService" default-request-channel="requestChannel" default-reply-channel="replyChannel">
    <int:method name="doSomething" payload-expression="#args[0] + ',' + #args[1]">
        <int:header name="method_name" value="login"/>
        <int:header name="service_identifier" value="myService"/>
        </int:method>                
</int:gateway>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="gatewayChannel">
       <int:header name="user_context" expression="T(UserContextHolder).getContext()"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="gatewayChannel" url="myURL" mapped-request-headers="user_context, service_identifier, method_name, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
          http-method="POST" reply-channel="replyChannel"/>
```

Where UserContext could be a java object

```
UserContext implements Serializable {
    String userId;
    RequestParameters params;
    ScopeEnum scope;
    ....
}
```

The problem I have is header user_context is not mapped in the header. From the logs, I can see that the DefaultHttpHeaderMapper is requesting for a Converter or ConversionService. See below -

```
09:54:59,488 - WARN main      org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper - Header 'X-    user_context' with value 'UserContextImpl@5e3ca754' will not be set since it is not a String     and no Converter is available. Consider registering a Converter with ConversionService     (e.g., <int:converter>)
```

How do I do this please ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTTP headers are in key:value format and both key and value are strings. 
You try to send object as a HTTP header value which is not very wise (and almost impossible because there may be some limits on the size of headers - for example 8KB Apache default limit).

You have three options:

1. Consider not using HTTP outbound gateway and use JMS instead (the best one in my opinion)
2. Add transformer which will serialize `UserContext` to `String` (if it was relatively short string it would be ok, in the other case I'd not recommend it)
3. Implement custom converter UserContext->String as described in section `Datatype Channel Configuration` of the spring reference documentation:
   http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-configuration